# TablePress Pagination

Tags: html, css, wordpress, datatable

im using tablepress plugin on wordpress and im trying to achieve this illustration: https://imgur.com/pG6eVhD with my pagination. how do i make the text 'previous' and 'next' appear outside the buttons and replaced with the text 'page 1 of X' instead?

this is how my current pagination looks like on my website: https://jolly-hawking7722.on.getshifter.io/ using this code:

```
.dataTables_paginate a {
    font-family: Montserrat;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}

.dataTables_paginate {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
}

.paging_simple .paginate_button.previous,
.paging_simple .paginate_button.next {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right,#fbcabb,#ceb6d9);
    border-radius: 15px;
}

.paging_simple .paginate_button.previous,
.paging_simple .paginate_button.previous:before,
.paging_simple .paginate_button.next {
    padding: 10px 40px;
}
```

Comment: I've checked the documentation, apparently it's not possible with this plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding these custom CSS into your Wordpress site for the style.

> replaced with the text 'page 1 of X' instead?

For this requirement, I think you need to modify the source code of the plugin?

Result as I inspected using these CSS:
[image]

```
.paging_simple .paginate_button.previous, .paging_simple .paginate_button.next {
    background: none !important;
}
.paging_simple .paginate_button.previous::before,
.paging_simple .paginate_button.next::after {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', 'Segoe UI', sans-serif !important;;
    line-height: 0.7em !important;
}
.paging_simple .paginate_button.previous::before {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right,#fbcabb,#ceb6d9);
  border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 10px !important;
}

.paging_simple .paginate_button.next::after {
        background-image: linear-gradient(to right,#fbcabb,#ceb6d9);
  border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 10px !important;
    right: -14px !important;
}
```

Comment: is it possible to change the font-family of the arrows to something like Montserrat?

Comment: @dakldw sure yes, I updated the code & line height adjusted

Comment: when i put that code in the arrows become squares, why? https://imgur.com/CFdnxWG

Comment: Could be a font problem? Can you inspect to see which font is being applied to it? I tested the code on your site & it works well http://prntscr.com/ogkb4x